# Support for multi-size .ico files in an ImageList

Tags: .net, ico

4 or 5 years back I reported the bug that MS does not support multi-sized .ico files in .NET.
The answer of one MS employee was that this was a bug, but not a critical one, so it would not be processed at the current point of time.

There is no fix / appropriate dealing with it to the current date.

Does anybody (successfully) deal with multi-size .ico files in .NET, or has everbody switched to the appropriate PNG files?

Comment: What are you using the Icon for?  Ico files seem to work fine for me in IE and for my Windows Apps (16x16, 32x32, etc) since Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Hi Eric, I am using these in an imagelist.

Comment: You are possibly mixing things up here.  An imagelist always provides images with a fixed size, doesn't have anything to do with multi-size icons.  Needs to work that way, ImageList provides images for a TreeView or ListView, they'd look rather bad if the images have random sizes.